# Magento 2 - new container not showing in overriden layout file

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, magento2.3.4, containers

I try to change the layout **vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml** in my own theme. I have overriden the layout file completly:

**app\design\frontend\company\base\Magento_Catalog\layout\override\base\catalog_product_view.xml**

I need to move the block **options_container** to a new container which I named **configurator**.

```
<container name="configurator.foo" htmlTag="div" htmlId="configurator_foo" after="product.info.main">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.info.form.options" as="options_container">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" name="product.info.options.default" as="default" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" name="product.info.options.text" as="text" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" name="product.info.options.file" as="file" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" name="product.info.options.select" as="select" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" name="product.info.options.date" as="date" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="Magento_Theme::js/calendar.phtml"/>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </block>
</container>
```

But the block is not showing, even after flushing all caches.

**Full layout file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/catalog/product/view.css"/>
    </head>

    <update handle="catalog_product_opengraph" />
    <update handle="page_calendar"/>

    <body>
        <attribute name="itemtype" value="http://schema.org/Product" />
        <attribute name="itemscope" value="itemscope"/>

        <!-- /** Remove the Product SKU information form the product detail page **/-->
            <referenceBlock name="sale.reorder.sidebar" remove="true"/>
            <referenceBlock name="skip_gallery_after" remove="true" />

        <!-- Add our custom breadcrumbs -->
            <referenceContainer name="content.top">
                <block class="Hausfux\Base\Block\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs" />
            </referenceContainer>

        <referenceBlock name="head.components">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="checkout_page_head_components"
                   template="Magento_Catalog::js/components.phtml"
            />
        </referenceBlock>

        <!-- (?) -->
            <referenceBlock name="root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>

        <referenceContainer name="content">

            <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product</argument>
                    <argument name="add_base_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="name"</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>

            <!-- Create mobile container, used to move elements into it on mobile view for reordering positions -->
                <container name="mobile_container_top" htmlTag="div" htmlId="mobile_container_top" before="-">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="mobile_container_template"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/mobile.phtml"
                    />
                </container>

            <!-- Produkt Info -->
                <container name="product.info.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-main" before="-">

                    <!-- Bewertungsanzeige -->
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.review"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/review.phtml"
                        />

                    <!-- Kurzbeschreibung -->
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.overview"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml"
                        >
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getShortDescription</argument>
                                <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">short_description</argument>
                                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">overview</argument>
                                <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Overview</argument>
                                <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="description"</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>

                    <!-- Links zum springen zu Produktdetails, Einbausituationen, Montageanleitungen -->
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="links"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/links.phtml"
                               after="product.info.overview"
                        />

                    <!-- Preis -->
                        <container name="product.info.price" label="Product info auxiliary container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-price">
                            <container name="product.info.stock.sku" label="Product auxiliary info" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-stock-sku">
                                <container name="product.info.type" before="-"/>
                            </container>

                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.final">
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                                    <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
                                    <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </block>
                        </container>

                    <!-- Gruppenpreis -->
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.tier" after="product.info.price">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                                <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">tier_price</argument>
                                <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>

                        <container name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" label="Alert Urls" after="product.price.tier"/>

                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/form.phtml"
                               after="alert.urls"
                        >
                            <container name="product.info.form.content" as="product_info_form_content">
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart"
                                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"
                                />
                            </container>
                        </block>

                    <!-- Vergleichsliste -->
                        <container name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" label="Product View Extra Hint">
                            <container name="product.info.social" label="Product social links container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-social-links">
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addto" as="addto"
                                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto.phtml"
                                >
                                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AddTo\Compare" name="view.addto.compare"
                                           after="view.addto.wishlist"
                                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addto/compare.phtml"
                                    >
                                        <arguments>
                                            <argument name="addToCompareViewModel" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Checker\AddToCompareAvailability</argument>
                                        </arguments>
                                    </block>
                                </block>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.mailto" 
                                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/mailto.phtml"
                                />
                            </container>
                        </container>
                </container>

            <!-- Media -->
                <container name="product.info.media" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product media" after="product.info.main">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery"
                           name="product.info.media.image"
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/gallery.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="gallery_options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\GalleryOptions</argument>
                            <argument name="imageHelper" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </container>

        <!-- Konfigurator -->
            <container name="configurator.foo" htmlTag="div" htmlId="configurator_foo" after="product.info.media">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.info.form.options" as="options_container">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" 
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper.phtml"
                    >
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" 
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options.phtml"
                        >
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" name="product.info.options.default" as="default" 
                                   template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/default.phtml"
                            />
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" name="product.info.options.text" as="text" 
                                   template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/text.phtml"
                            />
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" name="product.info.options.file" as="file" 
                                   template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/file.phtml"
                            />
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" name="product.info.options.select" as="select" 
                                   template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/select.phtml"
                            />
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" name="product.info.options.date" as="date" 
                                   template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/date.phtml"
                            />
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" 
                               template="Magento_Theme::js/calendar.phtml"
                        />
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" 
                           template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml"
                    >
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" 
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"
                        />
                    </block>
                </block>
            </container>


        <!-- Details Block -->
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Details" name="product.info.details"
                   template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/details.phtml"
                   after="configurator.foo"
            >

                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" as="description"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml"
                       group="detailed_info"
                >
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument>
                        <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">10</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>

                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Information</argument>
                        <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">20</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </block>

        <!-- Reviews -->
        <!-- Make review standalone -->
            <container name="product_review_wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlId="product_reviews_wrapper" after="-">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product_reviews_wrapper_block"
                       template="Magento_Review::product_review_wrapper.phtml"
                />

                <container name="product_review_content_wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlId="product_review_content_wrapper" after="-"/>
            </container>


        <!-- Cookies -->
            <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" 
                   template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml"
            >
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="compareProductLink" xsi:type="string">.action.tocompare</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            
        <!-- Product View Counter -->
            <block  class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Ui\ProductViewCounter" name="product_viewed_counter"
                    template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/counter.phtml"
            />

        </referenceContainer>


    <!-- Related, Upsell -->
        <referenceContainer name="content.aside">

            <!-- Related Products Slider -->
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related" name="catalog.product.related"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml"
                >
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">related</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="related.product.addto" as="addto">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare" name="related.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"
                        />
                    </block>
                </block>

            <!-- Upsell Products Slider -->
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell"
                       name="product.info.upsell" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">upsell</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="upsell.product.addto" as="addto">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare" name="upsell.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                               template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"
                        />
                    </block>
                </block>

            <!-- Additional (?) -->
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data"/>
        </referenceContainer>


        <!-- Unknown -->
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons\InCatalog" name="addtocart.shortcut.buttons"/>
            </referenceBlock>

            <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons\InCatalog" name="addtocart.shortcut.buttons.additional"/>
            </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: the layout path seems to be wrong. Try with app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Comment: No it is correct. I am overriding the layout. The layout file works, but the new container is not showing.

Comment: What exactly is showing?

Comment: @BenCrook, everything as usual, but the options are not showing anymore since I moved them to the new container which does not render.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to move the whole block:

```
<!-- Konfigurator -->
    <container name="configurator.foo" htmlTag="div" htmlId="configurator_foo" after="product.info.media">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/form.phtml" after="alert.urls">
            <container name="product.info.form.content" as="product_info_form_content">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
            </container>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.info.form.options" as="options_container">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options.phtml">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" name="product.info.options.default" as="default" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" name="product.info.options.text" as="text" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" name="product.info.options.file" as="file" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" name="product.info.options.select" as="select" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" name="product.info.options.date" as="date" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="Magento_Theme::js/calendar.phtml"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
    </container>
```

Because the block **options_container** only renders in the block **product.info**